# SQLite open performance-issue

Tags: c++, windows, performance, sqlite

I am writing a desktop application under windows,
I am using sqlite to store information,
I created a db with index on string column, insert a lot of informations, the db size about 16M,

If I restart Windows, and open my application.
It takes about 9-10 secodes to open the sqlite db.
The code is as follow:

```
int nRet;
nRet = sqlite3_open16(szFile, &mpDB);
if (nRet != SQLITE_OK)
{
   LPCTSTR szError = (LPCTSTR) _sqlite3_errmsg(mpDB);
   throw CppSQLite3Exception(nRet, (LPCTSTR)szError, DONT_DELETE_MSG);
}
setBusyTimeout(mnBusyTimeoutMs);
```

Is it possible to accelerate it ?

Many  Thanks!

Comment: Have you shutdown your database correctly?

Comment: How can I judge whether I closed the db correctly?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use sqlite3 command line utility to check your database.
Or you can recreate your tables with data (dump/restore).